# Is it ok to mkfs and mount the whole disk without partitionate

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, centos6

```
[root@VM_xxx_centos ~]# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        8255928 7068948    767604  91% /
/dev/vdb       516061624 5966928 483880296   2% /data2
```

As you can see I mount the whole `vdb` with no partitions. 
And I put the the following line in `fstab`

```
/dev/vdb             /data2         ext3 noatime,acl,user_xattr 1 0
```

> So is it OK to use the whole disk without partitionate ?

Comment: Yes, this is a virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's fine.

Please see: [Directly Formatting a Device on a Linux System](https://serverfault.com/questions/391448/directly-formatting-a-device-on-a-linux-system)

The best practices around this have changed over time. If this is a virtual machine, the case for not using partitions is more compelling.